# Angular HTTP returns Object instead of the requested type

Tags: angular, typescript, generics, rxjs

I'm new to TS and Angular, and having some trouble understanding either RXJS  observables or how JSON is unmarshalled into TS classes. I have an angular app with a class

```
class Entry {
  // ...

  clone(): Entry {}
}
```

and a service class

```
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";

class EntryService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient) { }

  getEntries(): Observable<Entry[]> {
    return this.http.get<Entry[]>(this.entriesURL)
      .pipe(
        tap(entries => {
          entries.map(entry => entry.moment = new Date(entry.moment))
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError('getEntries', []))
      );
  }

  // ...
}
```

and somewhere else there's a subscription

```
this.entryService.getEntries()
.subscribe(entries => this.entries = entries);
```

The problem is, the entries in the array that I get from the subscription aren't `Entry`s, they're just attributes with no `copy` method. If I do `console.log(entry.constructor.name)`, it prints out `Object`, and `entry.copy` is `undefined`. I assumed that setting the generic parameter would guarantee that the returned values had all the behavior of that class, but is there something else I need to do to get `http.get` to return full-fledged `Entry`s?

Comment: is your backend data returns `Entry` ?

Comment: That's expected. Angular doesn't know anything about your classes. It gets JSON, and just calls JSON.parse() to transform it into objects/arrays. You will never get instances of your class if you don't create them by yourself by invoking `new Entry()`. Types and generics don't exist at runtime. Typescript is a compiler, not a runtime. When you do `this.http.get<Entry[]>`, you're just lyong to yourself by telling the TypeScript compiler: trust me, this method will return an Observable<Entry[]>. But it won't.

Comment: Is there a common pattern that avoids this? For instance, would it make sense to keep all the data on one object and then pass it into another class that implements functions, or is it more common to just re-build your objects from the contents of the response manually?